# Using R & readr from Tidyverse: How to Import dataframe as Factor and with Labels

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I am using the R(-cran) & `readr` library from the Tidyverse.
I have a feature (column) from a .csv file that are factors, such as gender = c(0,1).

**Q**. How can I import the data as factors With Labels, so that they are more meaningful,
For example:

df.csv = c("male",0,1,0,1,0)

```
df <- read_csv("df.csv", 
               col_types = cols(male = col_factor(levels = c("0","1"), 
                                                  labels = c("F","M")))
```

However, I get the error:

```
Error in col_factor(levels = c("0", "1"), labels = c("F", "M")) : 
unused argument (labels = c("F", "M"))
```

However, I Want:  0="F" and 1="M".

Comment: Do it in 2 steps. Don't try to cram relabeling data inside your data reading function. There's nothing in the documentation to suggest that this is possible, so it's probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
df <- read_csv("df.csv", 
               col_types = cols(male = col_factor(levels = c("0","1"))))
# Followed by
df$column = factor(df$column, labels=c("F","M"))

str(df)
```

tibble [3,656 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)

$ male           : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...